# SQL Server: Multiple max and min values of various fields with respective timestamps in a single row resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with the following fields

```
Field1(REAL), Field2(REAL), ...Fieldn(REAL), DateNTime(TimeStamp)
```

in a table `table1`.

How can I get following resultset? i.e. max and min values of each field with corresponding timestamps

```
Max(Field1), Corresponding TimeStamp, Min(Field1), Corresponding TimeStamp, .....
```

similarily for other fields.

Thanks All,

Comment: Which version of SQLServer is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be something like this:

```
select 
    Field1_min, (select max(TimeStamp) from table1 where Field1 = Field1_min) as ts1min,
    Field1_max, (select max(TimeStamp) from table1 where Field1 = Field1_max) as ts1max,
    Field2_min, (select max(TimeStamp) from table1 where Field2 = Field2_min) as ts2min,
    Field2_max, (select max(TimeStamp) from table1 where Field2 = Field2_max) as ts2max,
    Field3_min, (select max(TimeStamp) from table1 where Field3 = Field3_min) as ts3min,
    Field3_max, (select max(TimeStamp) from table1 where Field3 = Field3_max) as ts3max,
    Field4_min, (select max(TimeStamp) from table1 where Field4 = Field4_min) as ts4min,
    Field4_max, (select max(TimeStamp) from table1 where Field4 = Field4_max) as ts4max
from (
    select
        min(Field1) as Field1_min, max(Field1) as Field1_max,
        min(Field2) as Field2_min, max(Field2) as Field2_max,
        min(Field3) as Field3_min, max(Field3) as Field3_max,
        min(Field4) as Field4_min, max(Field4) as Field4_max
    from table1
) S
```

Comment: Thanks Markus, Had used your query and the result is what we wanted.

Answer (score 2):

By using windowed functions:

```
with cte as
(select t.*
        max(Field1) over () MaxField1,  
        min(Field1) over () MinField1, ...
 from Table1 t)
select max(MaxField1) MaxField1,
       max(case Field1 when MaxField1 then DateNTime end) MxF1DateTime,
       min(MinField1) MinField1,
       min(case Field1 when MinField1 then DateNTime end) MnF1DateTime,
       ...
from cte
```